# I am not able to store intermediate array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, dom-events

I have a code for bubble sort:

```js
      var ani = []
export const Bubblesort =(arr) =>{
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     
        // Last i elements are already in place  
        for(var j = 0; j < ( arr.length - i -1 ); j++){
            
          // Checking if the item at present iteration 
          // is greater than the next iteration
          if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
            // If the condition is true then swap them
            var temp = arr[j]
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
            arr[j+1] = temp
          }
          console.log (arr)

        }
      }
      // Print the sorted array
      return arr
}
```

[image]

Here I want to get all the position of the elements in array
when I print the array, it shows me multiple array in my console. Like it should, but when I make it group of arrays, all the group array are having same number.

Replacing this

```
console.log (arr)
```

to this

```
 ani.push(arr)
 console.log(arr)
```

[image]

this gives me wrong output.
Please help.....

Comment: try `console.log(arr.slice())` - see, the console sometimes lies - not really, it shows the current state of things like Objects/Arrays, not the state they were in at the moment they are logged

Comment: The content of `arr` is a reference to an array. `.push(arr)` puts a copy of that reference into `ani`. You want an actual copy of the array referenced by `arr`, hence this should be a dupe of [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Comment: i tried creating copy of array using: "let unsortedarray  = arr.slice() " and then printed unsortedarray ,but no changes

Comment: i even tried console.log(unsortedarray.slice()) but not changes to the bug

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and not just parts of the actual script and some images

Comment: Hey guys I have solved my problem . I actually did arr.splice() instead of are.slice()   to print my array state . So because of my carelessness it created a problem . Sorry for the trouble guys. And thank you